# Apache and AWS HTTP to HTTPS Header Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, https, amazon-cloudfront, http-status-code-301

I am using AWS Cloudfront and AWS Loadbalancer to serve our website. The LB redirects to traffic coming from HTTP to HTTPS.
On Cloudfront you can add HEADERS and I added both apache2 config file and cloudfront security headers sections.

Now, when I check MAIN PAGE File via browser inspect I see 301 and 302 response and it does not response my headers. In contrast, when I click the javascript or css files it calls during download page, I can see my response header which I added both server and cloudfront.

How can I see my response headers on my main website page

x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=; includeSubDomains

Comment: Have you tried enabling HTTP to HTTPS redirect in CloudFront instead of on the load balancer?

Comment: it is already enabled http to https on loadbalancer. I solved the problem to write set header .htaccess file on apache server. I was looking for another solution instead of this because it gives load.

Comment: I realize you already had HTTP to HTTPS redirect working, but I was suggesting it might work differently if you enabled it at the CDN instead of the load balancer, and may solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is working right now. I can not solve the problem with cloudfront and elb, I manually wrote header set on .htaccess file for apache2. it is not good way to every request will be checked by htaccess file but this works.